# In Azure, can a public key vault manage access keys of a private storage account?

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-storage-account

I am following a scenario where I have created a storage account and have assigned a private endpoint to it. I have also applied network restrictions on the storage account through firewall settings so that it cannot be accessed over internet or any other network.
So I want to know that "Will the public key vault be able to manage(rotate or regenerate) access keys of this private storage account?". If so, then how can I verify that?

Answer (score 0):

- Since private endpoints and a firewall are used to isolate the
  storage account thus the key vault won't work as it does not come
  under the trusted services of Microsoft.
- The trusted services are those services which can work even under a   firewall.
- But this can be circumvented by granting access specifically to the key vault's ip address

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?msclkid=69dff770b37711ecad622790ab69b3ab&tabs=azure-portal) to grant access to IP addresses under firewall .

Also refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys-powershell#:%7E:text=Add%20a%20managed%20storage%20account%20to%20your%20Key,specifies%20NOT%20to%20regenerate%20the%20storage%20account%20keys.?msclkid=16d639b3b37b11ecb9ad69c2f42f896f) to create a key vault managed storage account.